# Python: installing pymongo with anaconda

Tags: python, pymongo, anaconda, conda

I've installed Anaconda (on ubuntu 12.04.03) and am trying to install `pymongo` so that conda recognizes it. I know there are similar questions floating around; but being new to Python, I would really appreciate an explicit answer to help me 'get going' - I'm failing currently :(

Cheers for any help

**EDIT:**

Seeing the question has been put on hold, I continued to persevere. When I run:

```
sudo pip install pymongo
```

it is installed to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` and Anaconda doesn't seem to import modules from this location (does anyone know how I can change this?). So instead, I ran:

```
sudo pip install -d anaconda/pkgs/ pymongo
tar -zxvf pymongo-2.6.3.tar.gz
cd pymongo-2.6.3/
python setup.py install
```

and now I am able to import `pymongo`. Is this the canonical way? I'm guessing not... like I said, I'm new to this, so any advice or input much appreciated.

Comment: You may want to take look at ["Python Packages and Environments with conda"](http://www.continuum.io/blog/conda) or then more specifically ["How do I install additional packages into Anaconda?"](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq.html#install-packages)

Comment: I can't add this as an answer until this is reopened, but you should use conda to install things when you can. `conda install pymongo`.

Comment: @asmeurer , the problem is there is no package; $ conda install pymongo => 
Fetching package metadata: ...
Error: No packages found matching: pymongo => So I have some questions at https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/100

Comment: OK! Try from my repo: "conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/annetheagile pymongo"